# Showing the logged-in user inside base.html (django)

Tags: django, django-templates

Is there a way to access the logged in user's firstname inside the base.html file?

I'm trying to do this, because i want to display who is currently logged in on the navigation bar, but it won't access the user's information, nor will it correctly check if the user is authenticated.

html inside base.html

```
            Hi there,

            {% if user.is_authenticated %}

                {{user.first_name}}
            {% else %}
                Stranger
            {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`request.user` gives you the user object that is currently logged in. So you have full access to all the attributes and methods the User class has. To get the `first_name`, you can do `{{ request.user.first_name }}`. To get the full name you use `{{ request.user.get_full_name }}`.

Comment: To avoid passing constantly using the word request, you can get the user instance inside your view and pass that variable explicitly when rendering your template.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `[RequestContext][1]`, by default you get `user` instance in your templates so you can use it as for its attributes as `{{user.first_name}}` and others. The `user` will be same a currently authenticated user which is also available in `request.user` in the views.

The `RequestContext` by default adds some default template contexts defined in `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` in your `settings.py`.

In your view, you can use it as

```
#your view code
....
#send response by rendering the template and use Requestcontext while rendering template
return render_to_response('polls/detail.html', {'poll': p},
                           context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Reference - [Django Tutorial 04](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial04/)